# Android Jasper Reporting

Tags: android, jasper-reports

Can Jasper Reporting be integrated into an Android application?  I'm trying to generate PDF, CSV, Text, and XLS reports from jrxml files.  However, I don't see that the package net.sf.jasperreports.engine is supported in the Android SDK.  Can anyone confirm that this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if it would be supported :). Jasper reports has too many dependencies to make it easily android compatible, but I can be wrong.
I would suggest writing a web application/web service exposing such a functionality through eg rest and then use that on the android platform.

Answer (score 0):

They have recently announced an Android SDK, you should try that [one](http://jasperforge.org/projects/androidsdk):

Comment: Yes there it is. But it's just an API to consume the services of an JasperReports server. So you got to have connection to it. In my case that's not the case: the report has to be compiled and created right on the device.