# How to implement a Java compiler and DEX converter into an Android app?

Tags: java, android, dex

While trying to find an answer to [Android Jasper Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7085943/1482507) I found out that there are two other questions to be answered therefor, which I been asked to ask as a question, not as an answer ;):

My questions are now: "Is there any compiler to use directly on the device" AND "how to execute such without rooting the device.
If anybody could give me a hint I would really appreciate it...

---

I looked a little time forward on this approach, and found apps which makes it possible to create APKs directly on an Android device which is NOT rooted:

- TerminalIDE - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside&hl=de
- JavaIDEdroid - http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/
- AIDE - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

Looks like they're using the compiler from eclipse and a ported dex converter. Now I'm trying to figure out how to do the same.

Sure: get the source code and look into it. But while I'm having curious problems to get a connection to the servers and trying to solve it, I follow the plea to ask this question here. Hoping both to help others with it and also getting an answer for myself ;)

---

I took the org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.3.v20120119-1537.jar from the plugin directory of my indigo and tried following code:

```
     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main ecjMain = new org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main(new PrintWriter(System.out), new PrintWriter(System.err), false/*noSystemExit*/, null, progress);
     System.err.println("compiling...");
     ecjMain.compile(new String[] {"-classpath", "/system/framework", storage.getAbsolutePath()+"/Test.java"});
     ecjMain.compile(new String[] {storage.getAbsolutePath()+"/Test.java"});
     System.err.println("compile succeeded!!!");
```

Sometimes the Exception was thrown that java.lang.Object could not be found and othertimes it stuck doing nothing while heating up my processor with 100% usage ... ...

At this time i could not figure out what is happening and why. And in cause that i have other work to do this part has to wait a little.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with [tag:compiler-construction]. You aren't constructing a compiler. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I succeeded after taking inspiration from source of [JavaIDEdroid](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/) and realizing that I'm dumb (for a time I tried to uses the compiler with the dexified framework classes on the device - which naturtally could not work).
After i succeeded compiling my Test.java with a copy of ADTs android-jar on sdcard I just had to load the classes with the DexClassLoader.
While informing myselft about how to do that I found this nice article [Custom Class Loading in Dalvik](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html)  which inspired me at least to write this piece of code:

```
    File storage = getDir("all41", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    System.err.println("copying the android.jar from asssets to the internal storage to make it available to the compiler");
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream dexWriter = null;
    int BUF_SIZE = 8 * 1024;
    try {
          bis = new BufferedInputStream(getAssets().open("android.jar"));
          dexWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(
              new FileOutputStream(storage.getAbsolutePath() + "/android.jar"));
          byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
          int len;
          while((len = bis.read(buf, 0, BUF_SIZE)) > 0) {
              dexWriter.write(buf, 0, len);
          }
          dexWriter.close();
          bis.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error while copying from assets: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.err.println("instantiating the compiler and compiling the java file"); 
    org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main ecjMain = new org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main(new PrintWriter(System.out), new PrintWriter(System.err), false/*noSystemExit*/, null);
    ecjMain.compile(new String[] {"-classpath", storage.getAbsolutePath()+"/android.jar", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Test.java"});


    System.err.println("calling DEX and dexifying the test class"); 
    com.android.dx.command.Main.main(new String[] {"--dex", "--output=" + storage.getAbsolutePath() + "/Test.zip", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/./Test.class"});


    System.err.println("instantiating DexClassLoader, loading class and invoking toString()");
    DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(storage.getAbsolutePath() + "/Test.zip", storage.getAbsolutePath(), null, getClassLoader());
    try {
        Class libProviderClazz = cl.loadClass("Test");
        Object instance = libProviderClazz.newInstance();
        System.err.println(instance.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error while instanciating object: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The Test.java only contains one method:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Hallo Welt!";
}
```

To get it running you need the jars jdt-compiler-x.x.x.jar (found in plugins directory of eclipse) and dx.jar (found in directory platform-tools/lib of Android SDK)

---

Not really hard ;) 
And now I will find out what to change in source of JasperReports to get it work on our beloved Android devices :D

Comment: Can you say how you managed to run dex file in android terminal. Did write your own terminal?

Comment: @BRUCE Sorry, after 8 years I do not recall specific details :/ I do not even think it would help you, the versions should be quite different from those days. But if you have specific problems or errors feel free to create questions for those as well :)